# Errors and problems while installing AutoPy

Tags: python, autopy

I want to install AutoPy for a particular python program.

but when i run `pip install -U autopy` then this error comes up :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/11vFBWXxNCnBptY3Qm_maP41yQ-lYFgAc/view?usp=sharing

I have Rust Nightly and the C++ compiler from Visual Studio.

Please help.

I use a Windows machine, Python 3.9, and I use Visual Studio Code as the Code Editor.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Also i cannot use PyAutoGui for the same program, thats why i need AutoPy

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I needed AutoPy for Python 3.9, but AutoPy supports only till Python 3.8. Hence the error was occurring. Just install Python 3.8 and it sould work.

Python download - https://www.python.org/downloads/